# How to kill batch job session in Unix?

Tags: sql, unix, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have shell script (batch job) to run the Oracle package from unix environment. I do not have oracle system access to kill the session..

From unix how to kill the session.

In oracle i have used below query to kill but i do not have privileges.

ALTER system KILL SESSION '2181,52254'

QL Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Please tell me how to kill the shell script session in unix?

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -aef | grep userID
```

Look for the process that you want to kill. Note the process ID which is the second column.

```
kill -9 <processID>
```

Comment: Just a heads up -9 is forceful killing. Use wisely. :)

Comment: i didn't find out the exact session id.. I am seeing below list only.. which is recent sessions..

-bash-3.2$ ps -aef | grep batchadm
batchadm  2665 32627  0 07:51 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -aef
batchadm  2666 32627  0 07:51 pts/0    00:00:00 grep batchadm
root     32622  4255  0 07:49 ?        00:00:00 sshd: batchadm [priv]
batchadm 32626 32622  0 07:49 ?        00:00:00 sshd: batchadm@pts/0
batchadm 32627 32626  0 07:49 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash

Comment: I am not seeing the session in Unix, But still i could see the session which loced in oracle.. v$session table...

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for this: You are not the owner of the process or the process is running on a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You get the OS process to `kill` by looking at the `v$process.spid` column (not `pid`!). You may find v$process row by joining `v$process.addr=v$session.paddr`.

Of course you need to perform kill on the OS where the database is, not on the database's client. You need OS privilege; normally on Unix, you need to become either root or oracle user on the database server.